# How do I find the equation of the position of a free falling object?

Tags: vectors

How I can find end coordinate of falling ball?

What parameters do I need? How to calculate it?

I think I need height, air speed, air pressure, weight of object, initial coordinates and from where air coming.

By vector I just found time fall ($t$) and velocity.

For example:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
v_{0} = 0 m/s\\ 
m = 2kg\\
h_{0} = 200m\\
v_{\text{air}} = 5 m/s\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

(iY = 49.7977973 and iX = 49.7977973)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

According to Newton's second law, we may claim that
\begin{align*}
R = \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}
\end{align*}

where $R$ is the resulting force acting on the particle and $p$ is the linear momentum.

If we consider that the only forces acting on the particle are the gravitational force and the air resistance, we get
\begin{align*}
ma = mg - kv^{2}
\end{align*}
where $m$ equals the mass (which was considered constant), $a$ denotes the acceleration, $g$ indicates the gravity, $k$ is a constant which depends on the shape of the falling body and $v$ is the speed, where $a$ is the derivative of $v$. Precisely, $a = v'$.

Hence we are led to solve the following ODE:
\begin{align*}
mv' = mg - kv^{2}
\end{align*}

which is separable.

If you want to disregard the air resistance, it suffices to take $k = 0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you please give a example ?

Comment: You can (conveniently) choose $m = 1$, $g = 10$ and $k = 1$ (I did not mention the units on purpose). Then you get the ODE to solve:
\begin{align*}
v' = g - v^{2} & \Longleftrightarrow \int\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{g - v^{2}} = \int\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

Comment: How i can get end position ? x and y

Comment: @user6011588 could you please provide some context? It may be the case that we are not talking about the same thing.

Comment: I making UAV that will drop ball, but i want to know where will fall ball

Comment: sight for a falling object